# How to create Alexa behavior on Echo Dot that is an alarm sound (or text-to-speech) that continues until dismissed

Tags: smart-home, sensors, alexa, amazon-echo

I bought a [YoLink water sensor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084WYB8PM) (leak detector).

By following [these steps](https://youtu.be/3uqYph4Gydg?t=202), I was able to link it to my Alexa app and Echo Dot. Now, when water touches the sensor, Alexa sends a notification to my phone and speaks through the Echo Dot "Leak detected."

This behavior achieves the goal if I either am within earshot of the Echo Dot *or* have my phone with me and online and I'm paying attention to it.

However, imagine that a friend of mine (whose phone isn't connected to my Alexa and wouldn't receive the notifications) is in the house, and I'm out somewhere else with my phone turned off. And the friend doesn't hear the brief notice from the Echo Dot.

I want Alexa to continuously alert the inhabitants about the leak until someone dismisses the alert.

How can I create that behavior?

key words: loop, loops, looping, skill

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone would comment on why this question deserves a downvote. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I really wouldn't worry about a single downvote. If someone thinks there is a serious issue with the post, they will flag for closure in which case we'll have a bit more of an idea what they think the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this feature is newly available, or probably I somehow missed it earlier.

I just needed to click "Add action", then "Custom", then type "Set alarm in 5 seconds".

[image: Custom]

[image: Enter what you would]

[image: Edit Routine]